# How to fix 503 error when I try to post on Safari IOS with my mailchimp form

Tags: javascript, html, mailchimp

When I embed a form from my mailchimp account it works on all browsers.
Except Safari on IOS. I get a 503 error and the post request is not executed. When I use the form on Chrome it does work. All desktop browsers also work. What could it be that only Safari on Iphones give a 503 error.

I did try to remove target="_blank" or remove the hidden input field for bot prevention